# Double RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these rewrite rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ([0-9A-Za-z_]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /dab.php?banner=$1&mid=$3&iid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ([0-9A-Za-z_]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /dab.php?banner=$1&mid=$3&iid=$2&url=$4 [L]
```

Them should redirect me to:

```
/dab.php?banner=$1&mid=$3&iid=$2
```

if there are only 2 slashes, and to:

```
dab.php?banner=$1&mid=$3&iid=$2&url=$4
```

if there are 3 slashes.

Instead it gives me error 404 not found if I add the 3rd slash and a content after it.
How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a `^` to bind your match to the entire URI. The regex: `([0-9A-Za-z_]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$` matches 3 slashes, but just after the first slash, which isn't what you want:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z_]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /dab.php?banner=$1&mid=$3&iid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z_]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /dab.php?banner=$1&mid=$3&iid=$2$url=$4 [L]
```

Comment: @PurpleFoxy The `http://` stuff isn't even part of the match. If the URI is: `http://example.com/abc/123/789`?foo=bar, then the *only* thing that is matched against in a rewrite rule is: `/abc/123/789`.